# How to disable THP on Centos 7 for mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos, centos7

I just installed a fresh instance of a Centos 7

```
Linux version 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 03:04:26 UTC 2015
```

I installed a mongodb 3.0 and when I connect I have this weird message:

```
2015-04-15T07:48:55.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-04-15T07:48:55.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-04-15T07:48:55.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2015-04-15T07:48:55.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-04-15T07:48:55.583+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
```

How do I disable THP for this version?

**Things I tried without luck**

I can disable it running this command:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

But when I reboot the problem appears again.

I tried to modify /etc/rc.local adding those lines:

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
  echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
exit 0
```

made a reboot and no results

I also tried to modify /etc/default/grub ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, and solved it by writing this in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled;
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag;
```

I also gave execution permissions to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

Now thb are disabled every time I boot.

Comment: I give you a vote up, cause you did the fix on my production server *trollface*

Comment: Also it worth checking that mongodb, redis etc, aren't starting before rc.local is executed.

Comment: No need to make rc.local executable.